# Matplotlib and pie/donut chart labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

If yall had seen my previous question, I am coding a Python program to evaluate the data that I collect while playing a game of Clue. I have decided to implement a GUI (tkinter) into my program to make it faster and easier to work with. One of the main window's of the GUI illustrates the different cards that I know each player has in their hand, the cards that I know must be in the middle "the murder cards", and the unknown cards that are inconclusively placed in the above categories. I have decided to implement this data through a matplotlib pie chart, five wedges for each of the previously mentioned categories.

Right now, I am unconcerned with how I implement this matplotlib function into my tkinter widget. I am solely focused on the design of the chart.

So far, I have documented the cards that are within each player's hand within a dictionary, wherein the keys are the player names, and the values are a set of cards that are in their hand. For example...

```
player_cards = { 'player1':{'Mustard', 'Scarlet', 'Revolver', 'Knife', 'Ballroom', 'Library'}, 'player2':{}, 'player3':{} }
```

So the data for the first three wedges of the pie chart will be extracted from the dictionary. For the other two wedges, the data will be stored within similarly organized sets.

After looking at the matplotlib.org website I have seen a example that sorta demonstrates what I am looking for...

[image]

with the code...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

recipe = ["225 g flour",
      "90 g sugar",
      "1 egg",
      "60 g butter",
      "100 ml milk",
      "1/2 package of yeast"]

data = [225, 90, 50, 60, 100, 5]

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5), startangle=-40)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(xycoords='data', textcoords='data',  arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"), bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(recipe[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
             horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

ax.set_title("Matplotlib bakery: A donut")

plt.show()
```

However, what is lacking from this example code is... (1) The label for each wedge is a single string rather than a set of strings (which is what stores the cards in each player's hand). (2) I cannot seem to control the color of the wedges. (3) the outline of each wedge is black, rather than white which is the background color of my GUI window. (4) I want to control the exact placement of the labels. And finally (5) I need the change the font/size of the labels. Other than that the example code is perfect.

Just note that the actual size of each wedge in the pie chart will be dictated by the size of each of the five sets (so they will add up to 21).

Just in case that you all need some more substantive code to work with, here are five sets that make up the data needed for this pie chart...

```
player1_cards = {'Mustard', 'Plum', 'Revolver', 'Rope', 'Ballroom', 'Library'}
player2_cards = {'Scarlet', 'White', 'Candlestick'}
player3_cards = {'Green', 'Library', 'Kitchen', 'Conservatory'}
middle_cards = {'Peacock'}
unknown_cards = {'Lead Pipe', 'Wrench', 'Knife', 'Hall', 'Lounge', 'Dining Room, 'Study'}
```

Okay that it, sorry for a rather long post, and thanks for those of you viewing and responding :)

Comment: These are too many questions. In essence, you ask us to write your script. This will probably not happen. Some comments: I would use lists or an ordered dictionary, a dictionary does not keep the order. (1) You can join the strings with "\n". (2) p.set_color() sets the color of the wedge in the loop (3) p.set_edgecolor() the, well, edge color.

Comment: In addition, (4) the position of the labels is set via `xytext` so you have full control over where to place them. (5) There are also examples on how to change the font size on the matplotlib page.

Comment: Hey. Yeah I did include way to much and I really didn't expect anyway to spend their time writing an entire script. I was just hoping someone would identify the functions (like you two did) that would work in conjunction with the example code I laid out from the matplotlib website. Thanks for you help, and I am interested in the "ordered dictionaries" that you have suggested.